# ParseLoginSampleBasic giving exception when I push the Log In button on the first screen (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I just started developing with parse. I downloaded the android ParseLoginUI and the sample apps. Two things I had done to be able to start the app: for ParseLoginUI add a reference to the FacebookSDK and copy the "bolts-android-1.1.2.jar" file from the FacebookSDK libs folder to the ParseLoginUI lib folder.

The ParseLoginSampleBasic runs, the first screen comes up, but when I click on the Log in button , this exception comes up:

```
12-05 12:02:31.151: E/dalvikvm(24615): Could not find class 'com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity', referenced from method com.parse.ui.ParseLoginBuilder.build
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615): Process: com.parse.loginsample.basic, PID: 24615
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at com.parse.ui.ParseLoginBuilder.build(ParseLoginBuilder.java:309)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at com.parse.loginsample.basic.SampleProfileActivity$1.onClick(SampleProfileActivity.java:71)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18482)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-05 12:02:32.606: E/AndroidRuntime(24615):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```